# Updating page elements immediately on input changes with django and AJAX inside GET request

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to update elements in the page to tell a user in real-time how many objects will be affected by their choice of criteria in a form.

For an example to work with, the form asks for a number and the django logic will delete any model instance with a `pk` less than that value once the submit button is clicked - but before clicking the user wants to know how many they will be deleting:

`<span id="number-changed">NULL</span> objects will be deleted`

so the end result I want is that `#number-changed` will be populated by a value like `MyModel.objects.filter(pk__lt=input_number).count()`.

I have set up an AJAX call on changes to the `input` via:

```
 $("input").change( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'myapp:bulkdelete' %}",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
        // code to update #number-changed
        }
```

I am wondering how I implement in the view so that on successful `GET` the `success` function can use the value I retrieve. Some pseudo-code:

```
# views.py
class MyView(FormView):
    # ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        input_number = ???  
        number_changed = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__lt=input_number).count()
        # presumably some super().get() call here
        return ???
```

Questions:

Can I retrieve the current `input_number` via `request` or does it need to be passed as a `url` parameter when making the AJAX request?

How can I add my required information, `number_changed` in this case, to the return of the `get()` method, and how to access this inside `success`?

The way I have implemented AJAX with django before has being using `POST` requests and I simply return a `JsonResponse` with my required data. However, an initial `get()` is called when loading the page and needs to return a full `HttpResponse` - so ultimately is there a way to add my additional information into this, or am I going about it completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ajax request is exactly the same as any other request from the point of view of the server. You can just include the data in the querystring, which you then access in the view via the `request.GET` dict.

jQuery will generate that querystring for you from the `data` parameter; note, you don't need a csrf token for a GET request. So:

```
    type: "GET",
    url: "{% url 'myapp:bulkdelete' %}",
    data: {
        input_number: $(this).val(),
    },
    ...
```

And in the view:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    input_number = request.GET["input_number"]
```

Comment: thanks, sent me down the right road. Some more info in case it's useful to others finding this: In `get()` I return `super().get()` if `request.GET` does not contain `input_number` (i.e. first page load), otherwise I create a `JsonResponse` from a dict of the values I want AJAX to use in `success()` (`number_changed` in the example).